# HTML/CSS - Entire Area Clickable Position Absolute Causing Mysterious White Space

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a whole area clickable as a link rather than just its text. Why are my attempts at doing this (position:absolute; width:90%) causing half of the purple area to just disappear?

```html
<h2 id="block-50a924-1451-4d" class="wp-block-gutenbee-heading block-50a924-1451-4d has-text-color has-background-color" style="color:#ffffff;background-color:#cf2f74">
 <a href="https://blog.samueljgodwin.co.uk/category/code/" style="content:'';position:absolute;width:90%; outline: 4px solid red; overflow: hidden">
  <mark style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)" class="has-inline-color has-white-color">
  Code
  </mark>
 </a>
</h2>
<style>.wp-block-gutenbee-heading.block-50a924-1451-4d { padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; font-size: 20px; }
</style>
```

I have left a red outline to show the clickable area in question, and the area as it appears using the above code.

[image]

What I want it to look like is something more like this...

[image]

...and the whole area be clickable.

Here is an example of the desired look, with only the text clickable.

```html
<h2 id="block-409604-bc85-4c" class="wp-block-gutenbee-heading block-409604-bc85-4c has-text-color has-background-color" style="color:#ffffff;background-color:#3b8dd6">
 <a href="https://blog.samueljgodwin.co.uk/category/lifestyle/">
  <mark style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)" class="has-inline-color has-white-color">
  Lifestyle
  </mark>
 </a>
</h2>
<style>.wp-block-gutenbee-heading.block-409604-bc85-4c { padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; font-size: 20px; }
</style>
```

My attempt at expanded this area seems to be chopping the containing block away.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `h2` tag with `a`!

```html
  <a href="https://blog.samueljgodwin.co.uk/category/lifestyle/">
<h2 id="block-409604-bc85-4c" class="wp-block-gutenbee-heading block-409604-bc85-4c has-text-color has-background-color" style="color:#ffffff;background-color:#3b8dd6">
<mark style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)" class="has-inline-color has-white-color">
  Lifestyle
</mark>
</h2>
  </a>
   
<style>.wp-block-gutenbee-heading.block-409604-bc85-4c { padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; font-size: 20px; }
</style>
```